# Is there any way to deploy profiles and Organization Wide Defaults and Field Level Security using deployment from repository?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, deployment, profile, metadata

Is there any way to do this?

- OWD: will it be deployed when metadata of objects will be deployed?
- Field level security: should it be deployed during the deployment of profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OWD: will it be deployed when metadata of objects will be deployed?

If provided, yes.

> Field level security: should it be deployed during the deployment of profiles?

For new fields, you must set the FLS or it will default to "hidden" unless set as "required". For existing fields, you can omit FLS and it will remain as it was. For new profiles, all fields must have their FLS set initially. It's usually better to always deploy FLS than not.